# Docker: mounting local directories as a non-root user in a container

Tags: docker, containers

I've read quite a few threads on the internet about how to best mount local (project) directories into a Docker container so that the directories are not owned by the `root` user. Unfortunately, I've not found a precise answer.

I'm building my development stack with this `docker-compose.yml` ([SfDocker](https://github.com/advancingu/SfDocker)) file:

```
db:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
    - "3306:3306"
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: symfonyrootpass
        MYSQL_DATABASE: symfony
        MYSQL_USER: symfony
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: symfonypass
worker:
    image: symfony/worker-dev
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
    environment:
        XDEBUG_HOST: 192.168.1.194
        XDEBUG_PORT: 9000
        XDEBUG_REMOTE_MODE: req
    links:
    - db
    volumes:
    - "var/nginx/:/var/log/nginx"
    - symfony-code:/var/www/app
```

Volumes are mounted at runtime only after the images are built. I've added a new user by `RUN groupadd -r luqo33 && useradd -r -g luqo33 luqo33` in the `symfony/worker-dev` image, but I was not able to `chmod` the mounted volumes so that it is owned by `luqo33:www-data`. I've tried to do it by:

1. Copying and running an `entrypoint.sh` with `chmod` command:

   COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
   RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
   ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]

The container would start and then shut down with no apparent reason.

2. Executing `CMD chown -R luqo33:www-data` while starting containers - this could not work because at the time of starting the `worker-dev` container, the volumes seem not to be mounted yet.

I did not manage to set the ownership of the mounted directories to users other than `root`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: " at the time of starting the worker-dev container, the volumes seem not to be mounted yet." Are you using boot2docker on Mac?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be a bit confused about how Docker works, especially with regard to entrypoint and cmd scripts.

Any script referenced in an ENTRYPOINT or CMD instruction will be executed by the container at run-time. Once the script finishes, the container will exit. For this reason, you will need to both run your chmod and start the application in the script.

If the current user is root, a script like the following should work fine to set permissions and start the app:

```
#!/bin/bash

chown -R luqo33:www-data /var/www/app
sudo -u luqo33 exec start-my-app-in-foreground-script-or-bin
```

There is a slight problem with sudo creating two processes however, so you may want to use [gosu](https://github.com/tianon/gosu) instead.

Comment: Hi Adrian. Once again thank you for help. "you will need to both run your chmod and start the application in the script". Does that mean that I'll have to run the `chown` script and then start the containter again (since it will exits after running the `chown`) command? Also, should I first `ADD` the script file and then execute it by `CMD` in my Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes, you have to `add` first

Comment: There's no "start the container again", you start it in the script after running the chown, have a look at my example. Yes, you need to COPY or ADD the script first and refer to it in an ENTRYPOINT or CMD instruction. Maybe you should have a look at the docs or a tutorial on-line?

Comment: @AdrianMouat, I'm not sure how I should `start-my-app-in-foreground-script-or-bin` since the container that I'm trying to run is an nginx with php-fpm. It should just run at all times so that it will server the website (the website is the mounted directory for which I want to change ownership). It's a bit annoying that it would exit after setting proper ownership - I'd want it to keep running/ Sorry, I'm really confused with Docker at the moment. I've skimmed through the docs, but I'll definitely need to read it again.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid this is just basic unix stuff. All you want to do is start nginx in the foreground so that becomes the running application if you like (effectively the script doesn't finish).  If all you need to start is nginx, it will just be "nginx -g "daemon off;" or similar. If you need to start more processes, look into supervisord or runit.

Comment: @AdrianMouat, coming back once again to your answer. From what I read in the docs, if I put this script as an `ENTRYPOINT`, all commands from now on will be passed to it so the `ENTRYPOINT` is a better fit for containers that run as executables. I cannot refer to this script in the `CMD` as I already have one `CMD` in my Dockerfile.  The `CMD` I have runs `supervisord`, which in turn starts nginx and fpm (accroding to the docs there can be only one `CMD` in a Dockerfile). It seems such a simple task - mount a host directory as a non-root user in a container, but  it still remains so confusing

Comment: I think it's confusing because you don't seem to have a Linux/Unix background. Lots of the official images e.g. redis and mongo do exactly what you want. CMD statements are actually passed as arguments to the entrypoint, so they work together. I suggest you go back to the docs and try to understand how those images work.